# Customizing wp-activate.php

Tags: multisite, css, activation

Does anyone know how I can customise wp-activate.php?

It wraps the content in `<div id="content" class="widecolumn">`, however in my theme the main wrapper is `<div id="main">`

Presumably, I could just style `div#content.widecolumn` to be identical to `div#main`. But I am curious if anyone knows how to customise this file without editing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, this is very hacky.

What I ending up doing was creating two new page templates **Register** and **Activate** and creating two new WordPress pages using those templates and then using a filter in my `functions.php` file to modify the behaviour one **wpmu_signup_user_notification**.

Users will register on this new Register page and they will be sent an email linking to the new Activation page.

### Register Template

In the Register template, I copied the code from `wp-signup.php` and removed the following lines from the beginning:

```
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );    
require( './wp-blog-header.php' );
```

I also changed `<div id="content" class="widecolumn>` to `<div id="main">` so as to fit in with the template.

I also changed the form action value from `action="<?php echo network_site_url('wp-activate.php'); ?>"` to `action=""`

### Activate Template

In the Activate template, I copied the code from `wp-activate.php` and removed the following lines from the beginning:

```
define( 'WP_INSTALLING', true );  
/** Sets up the WordPress Environment. */  
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );  
require( './wp-blog-header.php' );
```

I changed `<div id="content" class="widecolumn>` to `<div id="main">` so as to fit in with the template.

Again, I changed all the form actions to `action=""`

### Functions.php

I copied the **wpmu_signup_user_notification** function from `wp-includes/ms-functions.php` into my `functions.php` file.

Renamed it so something unique: `af_wpmu_signup_user_notification`

Removed the following:

```
if ( !apply_filters('wpmu_signup_user_notification', $user, $user_email, $key, $meta) )
        return false;
```

I changed the line `site_url( "wp-activate.php/?key=$key" )` to `site_url( "activate/?key=$key" )` since **activate** is the page slug of my Activate page.

Then I applied it as a filter with the following code:

```
add_filter('wpmu_signup_user_notification', 'af_wpmu_signup_user_notification', 10, 4);
```

---

This seems to be working okay - I can modify these pages at will without affecting the core. Although this too feels a little too hacky.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to change return to false in your af_wpmu_signup_user_notification. Otherwise two mails will be sent to user. One with the old link and one with the new one.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem here is: `wp-activate.php` includes your `header.php` but not the `functions.php`. You may get fatal errors if you use functions in you header which are defined in your `functions.php`.

I use two new files in my themes:

- `header-activate.php` and
- `footer-activate.php`

When `wp-activate.php` is called the constant `WP_INSTALLING` is set to `TRUE` (for no obvious reason). I use that in my `header.php`: I include the `functions.php` and call my setup function.

### Start of my regular `header.php`

```
// on wp-activate.php this is FALSE
if ( ! function_exists( 't5_setup' ) )
{
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/functions.php';
    t5_setup();
}
if ( defined( 'WP_INSTALLING' ) and WP_INSTALLING )
{
    locate_template( 'header-activate.php', TRUE, TRUE );
    return;
}
```

So I prevent the execution of the regular header file and use a customized one.

### My `header-activate.php`

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
declare( encoding = 'UTF-8' );
?>
<!Doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> <?php body_class( ' ' ); ?>>
<head>
    <title><?php
    $current_title = wp_title( '|', FALSE, 'right' );
    print empty ( $current_title ) ? get_bloginfo( 'name' ) : $current_title . get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    ?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <?php
    wp_head();
    ?>
    <style>
#content
{
    background:     #333;
    background:     rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    border:         1px solid #000;
    border-radius:  10px;
    box-shadow:     0px 0px 10px #000;
    color:          #eee;
    font:           1em/1.45 sans-serif;
    margin:         140px auto;
    max-width:      400px;
    padding:        40px;
}
#key
{
    background:     #ccc;
    background:     rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    border:         0;
    color:          #eee;
    width:          100%;
}
#key:focus
{
    background:     #fff;
    color:          #000;
}
.submit
{
    text-align:     right;
}
#submit
{
    background:     #222;
    -ms-filter:         "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#444444', endColorstr='#222222')";
    background-image:   -o-linear-gradient(#444444,#222222);
    background:         -webkit-linear-gradient(#444444,#222222);
    background:         -moz-linear-gradient(#444444,#222222);
    border:         2px solid #333;
    border-color:   #4d4d4d #333 #202020;
    border-radius:  7px;
    color:          #eee;
    width:          auto;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
```

As you can see, I use no external stylesheet. Not necessary. But the custom background image is still active.

I do the same in my `footer.php`:

### Start of the regular `footer.php`

```
if ( defined( 'WP_INSTALLING' ) and WP_INSTALLING )
{
    locate_template( 'footer-activate.php', TRUE, TRUE );
    return;
}
```

### Complete `footer-activate.php`

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
declare( encoding = 'UTF-8' );
wp_footer();
```

### Result

[image]

---

The whole process is way to hacky. I’m sure there are better ways to handle this.

Comment: This was very helpful. Not quite what I was trying to do (see my answer). But it solved the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I made the activate page same as the rest of the site by adding this:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to modify some of the text so I was able to filter gettext using this code put into mu-plugins/my-functions.php. It will NOT work putting this into a regular plugin, but you can put it into functions.php of your base theme.

```
function rgbook_activate_page_action() {
    add_filter('ngettext', 'rgbook_activate_page_change_text' );
    add_filter('gettext', 'rgbook_activate_page_change_text' );
}
add_action( 'activate_header', 'rgbook_activate_page_action' );

function rgbook_activate_page_change_text( $text ) {
    $search = '<a href="%1$s">Log in</a> or go back to the <a href="%2$s">homepage</a>.';
    $replace = '<a href="%1$s">Click here to log in now</a>.';

    return str_ireplace($search, $replace, $text);
}
```